# Quotients of topological groups

Tags: general-topology

Theorem: Suppose that $G$ is a left topological group with identity $e$ and a topology $\mathcal{T}$, and $H$ is closed subgroup of $G$. Denote by $G/H$ the set of all left cosets $aH$ of $H$ in $G$, and endow it with the quotient topology with respect to the canonical mapping $\pi: G \rightarrow G/H$ defined by $\pi(a) = aH$, for each $a \in G$. Then the family $\{ \pi(xU): U \in \mathcal{T}, e \in U \}$ is local base of the space $G/H$ at the point $xH \in G/H$, the mapping $\pi$ is open and $G/H$ is a homogeneous $T_{1}$-space.

I will write only first three sentences of proof.

Proof: Clearly, set $xUH$ is the union of a family of left cosets $yH$, with $y \in xU$. Therefore, $\pi^{-1}(\pi(xUH)) = xUH$. Since the set $xUH$ is open in $G$ and the mapping $\pi$ is quotient, it follows that $\pi(xUH)$ is open in $G/H$.

Question: Why is set $xUH$ open in $G$?

We know that $G$ is left topological group. So left translations are homeomorphisms so they are open mappings. If $U$ is open, I understand that $\lambda_{x}(U) = xU$ is open. But I don't understand why is $xUH$ open when $H$ is closed.

Thanks. :D

Comment: Take more unions.

Comment: If you can somehow prove that $xUh$ is open for all $h\in H$, then that would be enough. I personally do not see why this is correct, but if you have a counterexample that would probably help.

Comment: If you know that left translation is a homeo, it’s believable that so is right translation.

Comment: I didn't try to prove if left translation is home then it is right translation. Thank you Randall for idea.

Comment: What is a "left" topological group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard result in the theory of topological groups.  If $G$ is a topological group and $U$ is an open set in $G$, then so is $xU$ and $Ux$ for any $x \in G$.  This just uses the facts that both left- and right translation by $x$ is always a homeomorphism.  By taking plenty of unions you get your result.

If $U$ is open then so is $xU$ for your $x \in G$.  Now, for each $h \in H$ we see that $xUh$ is also open.  But $xUH = \bigcup_{h \in H} xUh$ is now a union of open sets, so is open.

Comment: Why is $Ux$ open for open $U$? Only multiplication on the left is continuous in the question's setting

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti  that was an edit to the question after I had already answered.

Comment: The edit history shows that the question has been about left topological groups from the very beginning and that only spelling was edited as far as I can see (and in any case at the time of writing the last edit is from 22h ago, and your answer is from 7h ago)